# re module - what is the r notation?

Tags: python, regex

I am try to understand this code:

```
Var1 = re.compile(r"nothing is (\d+)").search
```

i am want to see what is the affect of the r notation right after the ( sign on the \d.
i know that \d mean to find decimal numbers (the \ mean that d has a special meaning), is that mean that without the r notation i would use \ ? if so why ?
i know that at the bash shell it is enough to put just one \ .

i have read here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#raw-string-notation

but i'm can't understand how it affects the snippets code above.
Thanks.

Comment: Your code sample seems to be incomplete. Is that the entire line?

Comment: you are right it has to be in a variable, but besides that it is the entire line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [raw string literal](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). It changes backslashes to be treated literally (almost, see below). This is particularly useful when writing regular expressions as they often contain backslashes and if you use ordinary string literal you may have to escape the backslashes, making the regular expression harder to read.

Without the `r` your code would look like this:

```
f = re.compile("nothing is (\\d+)").search
```

Note that not escaping the backslashes also works in this case because `'\d'` is not a valid escape sequence:

```
f = re.compile("nothing is (\d+)").search
```

However, relying on this behaviour may result in errors unless you (and everyone who has to maintain your code) can memorize the list of allowable escape sequences.

---

The rules for raw string literals are:

> When an `'r'` or `'R'` prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal `r"\n"` consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase `'n'`. String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"` is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the string, not as a line continuation.

Comment: Whoa, didn't realize we can't do a single backslash (`r'\'`) in a raw string literal.

Comment: What a goofy special case - what purpose could it serve to allow the quote character to be escaped in a raw string?  It is impossible to create a raw string containing -- Bob said "hi" -- when the string is enclosed in double quotes because the backslash is not discarded.  -- Bob said \"hi\" -- is a useless result.

Comment: @Dave: That's why you usually don't escape quotes in Python, you write `'Bob said "hi"'` or `"""Bob said "hi""""` or `'''Bob said "hi"'''`.

Comment: as i am understand, you don't need to escape the \d because it is interpreted as a decimal sign, but with the 'r' is actually \\d ? if so why it isn't  interpreted as literal "\d" ?

Comment: @HananN.: No. You don't have to escape `\d` because it's not a valid escape sequence, so it is treated literally.

Comment: in case it treated literally, how it becomes to mean decimal numbers, why it isn't tell to re to find "\d"s on the string ?

Comment: @HananN. - there is a difference between string escape sequences (http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) and regular expression special sequences (http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).  In a string literal, \d is just two characters slash and d, that are interpreted when the string is passed to the regex parser.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Thanks, I know that single quotes can be used around a string containing double quotes.  What I'm wondering is why Python would be designed so that \" is an escape sequence instead of a literal slash at the end of a raw string - there's no benefit to that design.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks, finelly i'm understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Has nothing to do with `re`.

[Python string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) may start with `r`; these are called "raw strings" and backslash escapes are (mostly) not interpreted.